# Я хочу сохранить фото на свой компьютор полученное от юзера в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Вот исходный код

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def start(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id

        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = 'C:/Users/Timur/PycharmProjects/waltermark/documents/' + message.document.file_name;
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

но выдаёт ошибку

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_id'

Comment: Вы указали, что функция `start` обрабатывает сообщения с типом `photo`, но при этом внутри обращаетесь к полю `message.document`. Вам нужно использовать поле `message.photo`.